# DNS Server with bind9 cannot resolve reverse zone

Tags: networking, server, dns, bind

I have recently reconfigured my network and am trying to go through the process of changing all the servers over. In the process of doing this, I found that my dns/dhcp servers are having some issues. I have the forward zone working as expected, but I cannot for the life of me get the reverse zone to work. None of the logs are bringing up errors; dhcp has no issues updating the either zone; but arp, dig -x, and host do not resolve the ip to hostname. My server and network only work with ipv4, though localhost ipv6 statements have been left in.

Until the issue is resolved, the server firewall has been disabled. The failover server has also been disabled; except to move the master dhcp server from recover to normal to communication-interrupted. Server details and logs to follow:

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.4(amd64),
Kernel: 4.2.0-34-generic,
bind9: 1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.8,
isc-dhcp-server: 4.2.4-7ubuntu12.4,
Network(masked): 10.94.78.0/23

named.conf

```
// This is the primary configuration file for the BIND DNS server named.
//
// Please read /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz for information on  the 
// structure of BIND configuration files in Debian, *BEFORE* you customize 
// this configuration file.
//
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.conf.local

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

controls {
inet 127.0.0.1 allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
inet 10.xxx.78.11 allow { 10.xxx.78.11; 10.xxx.78.13; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};

 logging {
     <Logging details omitted as it is working as expected>
      };

     category default { default_file; };
     category general { general_file; };
     category database { database_file; };
     category security { security_file; };
     category config { config_file; };
     category resolver { resolver_file; };
     category xfer-in { xfer-in_file; };
     category xfer-out { xfer-out_file; };
     category notify { notify_file; };
     category client { client_file; };
     category unmatched { unmatched_file; };
     category queries { queries_file; };
     category network { network_file; };
     category update { update_file; };
     category dispatch { dispatch_file; };
     category dnssec { dnssec_file; };
     category lame-servers { lame-servers_file; };
 };
```

named.conf.options

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
    // the all-0's placeholder.

        forwarders {

        // OpenDNS Servers
//                208.67.222.222; // Use for Primary
        //      208.67.220.220; // Use for Secondary

        // Google Public DNS
//                8.8.8.8; // Use for Primary
        //      8.8.4.4; // Use for Secondary
        };

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
#   dnssec-validation auto;
        dnssec-enable no;
        dnssec-validation no;
    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
#   listen-on-v6 { any; };

# added thanks to bigdinosaur.org
        allow-query {
                10.xxx.78/23;
                <VPN IPs omitted>
                127.0.0.1;
        };
        allow-transfer {
                10.xxx.78/23;
                127.0.0.1;
        };

};
```

named.conf.local

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
 include "/etc/rndc/rndc.key";
 include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
 include "/var/lib/bind/spywaredomains.zones";
 include "/var/lib/bind/ads.zones";

// Defining ACLs
acl "Secondary DNS" {
        10.xxx.78.xx;
};

// Defining Forward Lookup Zone
zone "hili-caffinated.local" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/db.hili-caffinated.local";
        allow-update { key "rndc-key"; };
        allow-transfer { "Secondary DNS"; };
};

// Defining Reverse Lookup Zone
zone "xxx.10.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master; 
//        notify no;
        file "/var/lib/bind/db.xxx.10.in-addr.arpa";
        allow-update { key "rndc-key"; };
        allow-transfer { "Secondary DNS"; };
};
```

named.conf.default-zones is the exact same as provided with package

db.hili-caffinated.local

```
;
; BIND data file for hili-caffinated.local
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     hcsvrxx.hili-caffinated.local. nseadm.hcsvr11.hili-caffinated.local. (
                      032816102         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      hcsvrxx.hili-caffinated.local.
@       IN      NS      hcsvrxx.hili-caffinated.local.
@       IN      PTR     hili-caffinated.local.
@       IN      A       10.xxx.78.xx
@       IN      AAAA    ::1
; Printers
hcptrxx IN      A       10.xxx.78.xx

<entries omitted after verified syntax is same as above>

; CNAME Entries
; hcptrxx
hp8600  IN      CNAME   hcptrxx
<entries omitted after verifying syntax is same as above>
```

db.xxx.10.in-addr.arpa

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for hili-caffinated .local
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     hcsvrxx.hili-caffinated.local. nseadm.hcsvrxx.hili-caffinated.local. (
                      032816202         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      hcsvrxx.hili-caffinated.local.
@       IN      NS      hcsvrxx.hili-caffinated.local.
; Printers
78.xx   IN  PTR hcptrxx.hili-caffinated.local.
<entries omitted after verifying syntax is same as above>

; Broadcast
79.255  IN  PTR hcbroadcast.hili-caffinated.local.
```

Ping results

```
PING hcwknxxx.hili-caffinated.local (10.xxx.78.xx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.xxx.78.xx: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.168 ms

--- hcwknxxx.hili-caffinated.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.168/0.168/0.168/0.000 ms
```

ARP results

```
arp 10.xxx.78.xx
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
10.xxx.78.xx              ether   <correct mac address>   C                     eth0
```

DIG -X results

```
dig -x 10.xxx.78.xx

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.8-Ubuntu <<>> -x 10.xxx.78.xx
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 39726
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;xx.78.xxx.10.in-addr.arpa. IN  PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
xxx.10.in-addr.arpa.    604800  IN  SOA hcsvrxx.hili-caffinated.local. <username_omitted>.hcsvrxx.hili-caffinated.local. 32816206 604800 86400 2419200 604800

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Mar 28 20:06:05 CDT 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 125
```

HOST results

```
host 10.xxx.78.xx
Host xx.78.xxx.10.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

SYSLOG from bind restart

```
Mar 28 21:03:47 hcsvrxx rbind.sh[5627]: root has restart the bind9 service...
Mar 28 21:03:48 hcsvrxx named[5687]: starting BIND 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.8-Ubuntu -u bind
Mar 28 21:03:48 hcsvrxx named[5687]: built with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--localstatedir=/var' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--with-atf=no' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-rrl' '--enable-filter-aaaa' 'CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing -DDIG_SIGCHASE -O2'
Mar 28 21:03:48 hcsvrxx named[5687]: ----------------------------------------------------
Mar 28 21:03:48 hcsvrxx named[5687]: BIND 9 is maintained by Internet Systems Consortium,
Mar 28 21:03:48 hcsvrxx named[5687]: Inc. (ISC), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit
Mar 28 21:03:48 hcsvrxx named[5687]: corporation.  Support and training for BIND 9 are
Mar 28 21:03:48 hcsvrxx named[5687]: available at https://www.isc.org/support
Mar 28 21:03:48 hcsvrxx named[5687]: ----------------------------------------------------
Mar 28 21:03:48 hcsvrxx named[5687]: adjusted limit on open files from 4096 to 1048576
Mar 28 21:03:48 hcsvrxx named[5687]: found 2 CPUs, using 2 worker threads
Mar 28 21:03:48 hcsvrxx named[5687]: using 2 UDP listeners per interface
Mar 28 21:03:48 hcsvrxx named[5687]: using up to 4096 sockets
Mar 28 21:03:48 hcsvrxx named[5687]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
Mar 28 21:03:49 hcsvrxx named[5687]: reading built-in trusted keys from file '/etc/bind/bind.keys'
Mar 28 21:03:49 hcsvrxx named[5687]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
Mar 28 21:03:49 hcsvrxx named[5687]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
Mar 28 21:03:49 hcsvrxx named[5687]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53
Mar 28 21:03:49 hcsvrxx named[5687]: listening on IPv4 interface eth0, 10.xxx.78.xx#53
Mar 28 21:03:49 hcsvrxx named[5687]: generating session key for dynamic DNS
Mar 28 21:03:49 hcsvrxx named[5687]: sizing zone task pool based on 17835 zones
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: set up managed keys zone for view _default, file 'managed-keys.bind'
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 64.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 65.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 66.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 67.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 68.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 69.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 70.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 71.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 72.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 73.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 74.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 75.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 76.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 77.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 78.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 79.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 80.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 81.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 82.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 83.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 84.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 85.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 86.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 87.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 88.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 89.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 90.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 91.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:50 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 92.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 93.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 94.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 95.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 96.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 97.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 98.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 99.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 100.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 101.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 102.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 103.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 104.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 105.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 106.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 107.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 108.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 109.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 110.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 111.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 112.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 113.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 114.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 115.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 116.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 117.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 118.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 119.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 120.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 121.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 122.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 123.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 124.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 125.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 126.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 127.100.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 254.169.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 2.0.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 100.51.198.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 113.0.203.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 255.255.255.255.IN-ADDR.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: D.F.IP6.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 8.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 9.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: A.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: B.E.F.IP6.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: automatic empty zone: 8.B.D.0.1.0.0.2.IP6.ARPA
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
Mar 28 21:03:51 hcsvrxx named[5687]: command channel listening on 10.xxx.78.xx#953
Mar 28 21:03:56 hcsvrxx rbind.sh[5694]: ...The bind9 service has restarted.
```

general.log

```
28-Mar-2016 13:37:16.169 running
28-Mar-2016 21:03:47.629 received control channel command 'stop -p'
28-Mar-2016 21:03:47.630 shutting down: flushing changes
28-Mar-2016 21:03:47.630 stopping command channel on 127.0.0.1#953
28-Mar-2016 21:03:47.630 stopping command channel on 10.xxx.78.xx#953
28-Mar-2016 21:03:48.010 exiting
28-Mar-2016 21:03:51.577 managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 4
28-Mar-2016 21:03:51.603 zone 200words.ae/IN: loaded serial 32816300
<Irrellevant zone entries omitted though very similar to above>
28-Mar-2016 21:03:54.975 zone hili-caffinated.local/IN: loaded serial 32816102
28-Mar-2016 21:03:54.975 zone glassbu.info/IN: loaded serial 32816300
<Irrellevant one entries omitted though very similar to above>
28-Mar-2016 21:03:51.635 zone xxx.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 32816202
28-Mar-2016 21:03:51.635 zone comunadepilar.gob.ar/IN: loaded serial 32816300
<Irrellevant one entries omitted though very similar to above>
28-Mar-2016 21:03:55.791 all zones loaded
28-Mar-2016 21:03:56.137 running
```

*Note: The irrellevant zones are created via the same script and all have worked in previous environment on same machine. Only network information has changed.

SYSLOG entry from dhcp exchange

```
Mar 28 22:14:47 hcsvrxx dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from xx:xx:xx:xx:96:d8 via eth0
Mar 28 22:14:48 hcsvrxx dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 10.xxx.78.xx to xx:xx:xx:xx:96:d8 (hcvmwdxx) via eth0
Mar 28 22:14:48 hcsvrxx dhcpd: Can't create new lease file: Permission denied
Mar 28 22:14:48 hcsvrxx dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.xxx.78.xx (10.xxx.78.xx) from xx:xx:xx:xx:96:d8 (hcvmwdxx) via eth0
Mar 28 22:14:48 hcsvrxx dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.xxx.78.xx to xx:xx:xx:xx:96:d8 (hcvmwdxx) via eth0
Mar 28 22:14:48 hcsvrxx dhcpd: Added new forward map from hcvmwdxx.hili-caffinated.local to 10.xxx.78.xx
Mar 28 22:14:48 hcsvrxx dhcpd: Added reverse map from xx.78.xxx.10.in-addr.arpa to hcvmwdxx.hili-caffinated.local
```

Note: the lease file is an issue currently being worked on by the appropriate people and does not need to be addressed here.

If you need anything else, please let me know.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have authoritive rights?  My last couple providers required Rdns to be handled by them.

Comment: What did you actually put here `zone "xxx.10.in-addr.arpa"` (its important, you can put a real example with changed values)? Add the contents of `/var/lib/bind/db.xxx.10.in-addr.arpa` file..

Comment: Thanks for the responses.
@Brian: yes, it's a private network and have confirmed all other servers have been disabled.

Comment: @heemayl zone"94.10.in-addr.arpa" and contents have been added.

Comment: Also note, I've tried zone "78.94.10.in-addr.arpa", and adding another reverse lookup zone "79.94.10.in-addr.arpa" to hold the other half of the network 10.94.79.0/23. Both those changes have been completely undone.

Comment: Sorry, that network is set to 10.94.78.0/23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the order of IP address octets in reverse `zone` file `/var/lib/bind/db.xxx.10.in-addr.arpa`.

In reverse `zone` declaration, you have used `xxx.10.in-addr.arpa` as the `$ORIGIN`, while in the zone file you have used:

```
78.xx   IN  PTR hcptrxx.hili-caffinated.local.
```

As a result, `10.xxx.xx.78` will resolves to `hcptrxx.hili-caffinated.local`, which is clearly not what you want.

Fix the order in the `PTR` record:

```
xx.78   IN  PTR hcptrxx.hili-caffinated.local.
```

which means `10.xxx.78.xx` will correctly resolves to `hcptrxx.hili-caffinated.local`.

Similarly, do:

```
255.79  IN  PTR hcbroadcast.hili-caffinated.local.
```

For the sake of understanding, remember that the IP octets are always work in reverse in reverse `zone` and `PTR` record declaration.